# MYSQL Update based on condition

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me to update a range of sizes by category on our X-cart shoping cart.

At the moment we have sizes listed over the years as

```
10mm
10mm (00g)
```

I need to change all size option of the products in a specific category from 10mm to 10mm (00g)

I thought that I could use something like

```
SELECT * FROM `xcart_categories` WHERE `categoryid` = "311"
UPDATE xcart_class_options
SET option_name = REPLACE(option_name, '10mm', '10mm (00g)')
```

But I not an SQL guy so any pointers would be great.

Comment: How are the xcart_categories and xcart_class_options tables related? Which table is the categoryid column in?

Comment: `REPLACE` operates on substrings, so this will change `110mm` to `110mm (00g)`. Is that desired?

Comment: categoryid is in a different table. I was using this to just select products from a certain category rather than doing a global find/replace as 10mm is used for gauge and length fields.

Comment: How are the tables related? I suspect a join is needed, but we need more information.

Comment: Xcart_categories contains the column categoryid and xcart_class_options contains the text I wish to change in the column option name - sorry for not explaining better first time out

Comment: And how are the two tables related? There needs to be a foreign key that relates them.

Comment: Other than being in the same database I am not sure, sorry, I think I am out of my comfort zone here.

Comment: Let me rephrase: How do you know which rows in `xcart_class_options` should be updated? You only want the ones related to the rows in `xcart_categories` with `categoryid = 311`, right? Can you show some sample data, or `show create table` of the two tables?

Comment: correct only the ones related should be changed

Comment: This is like pulling teeth? How do you tell which ones are related? There needs to be a column in each table that connects them. Like a class ID in the category table.

Comment: Yes, sorry and thanks for all your help, I have looked at the structure and cannot see a common connection. I think I will just pay the Russians to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE xcart_class_options
SET    option_name = REPLACE(option_name, '10mm', '10mm (00g)')   
WHERE  categoryid = '311'
```

Comment: You will get result like : `10mm (00g) (00g)`

Comment: Ja, true, if the update is ran multiple times, that could happen. The query above is intended to illustrate the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You just put the condition in the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE` statement, there's no need for `SELECT`.

```
UPDATE xcart_categories
SET option_name = REPLACE(option_name, '10mm', '10mm (00g)')
WHERE categoryid = '311'
AND option_name NOT LIKE '%10mm (00g)%'
```

The syntax of `UPDATE` is described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html).

Comment: You will get result like : `10mm (00g) (00g)`

Comment: @FabienTheSolution Thanks, I added a check. Your answer may be better if `10mm` is the entirety of the `option_name`, rather than a substring.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is also a `categoryid` column in the `xcart_class_options` table, you can do something like :

```
UPDATE xcart_class_options
SET option_name = '10mm (00g)'
WHERE option_name = '10mm' AND
      categoryid = '311';
```